# How to toggle main product image from multiple images

Tags: assets, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to properly update the main product image from a set of images that are available.

Within the product detail page, I have a large default image that is shown with a set of thumbnails below from lopping through all available images associated with the product.

I'm able to loop through and display all available images for the given product using.

```
<div class="product__photos">
{% set relatedAssets = product.productPhoto.all() %}

  {% if relatedAssets|length %}
    {% for rel in relatedAssets %}
      <div class="product__photo">
        <img src="{{ rel.getUrl('square_md') }}" alt="">
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %} 
</div>
```

What I'd like to do it update the large image once a thumbnail of the image set is clicked. I haven't been able to find anything related to successfully doing this which seems like a common pattern for an ecommerce site.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
{% set relatedAssets = product.productPhoto.all() %}
{% if relatedAssets|length %}

<img id="primaryImg" src="{{relatedAssets|first.getUrl() }}">

<div class="product__photos">

    {% for rel in relatedAssets %}
      <div class="product__photo">
        <a href="#" class="thumbImg" data-lrgimg="{{ rel.getUrl() }}"><img src="{{ rel.getUrl('square_md') }}" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endif %} 

</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".thumbImg").click(function(){
    $("#primaryImg").attr({ "src": $(this).data('lrgimg') });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Luke – worked like a charm!